# How prove $\pi^2>2^\pi$

Tags: analysis, inequality, pi

show that
$$\pi^2>2^\pi$$
I use computer found 
$$\pi^2-2^\pi\approx 1.044\cdots,$$

can  see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E2-2%5Epi)

I know 
$$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{\ln{\pi}}{\pi}>\dfrac{\ln{2}}{2}$$
so let
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\ln{x}}{x}$$
so
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2}=0,x=e$$
so $f(x)$ is Strictly increasing
 on $(2,e)$, and is Strictly decreasing
 on $(e,3) $
so I can't know $f(2)$ and $f(\pi)$ which is bigger?

maybe this problem exsit have easy methods by hand

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\frac{\ln 2}{2}=\frac{\ln 4}{4}.$$

Comment: As simple as it gets!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, we can prove $9 > 2^{\pi}$.

We are going to prove $\dfrac{9}{8} > 2^{0.16}$, i.e $\left(\dfrac{9}{8}\right)^6 > 2^{0.96}$

To see this we prove $\left(\dfrac{9}{8}\right)^6 > 2$, which can be verified by a bit direct computation

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966964/which-number-its-greater-pi3-or-3-pi/), asking which of $\pi^3$ and $3^\pi$ is bigger.  It can be deduced from the inequalities

$$3\lt\pi\lt{22\over7}$$

Specifically,

$$2^{11}=2048\lt2187=3^7\implies2^{22/7}\lt3^2\implies 2^\pi\lt\pi^2$$

Answer (score 1):

For $n>e$ $f(x)$-decreasing so $ln(\pi)/\pi>ln(4)/4$ but $ln(4)/4=ln(2)/2$