# Relation between two numbers

Tags: real-analysis

If $x=\pi^{3}$ and $y=3^{\pi}$ then what is the relation between x and y?

I have no idea of how to solve this problem. Also in general there is no relation between two numbers of this kind. So what is so special about this $\pi$ and 3.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: **Hint** Since $\log$ is increasing, we may as well compare $3 \log \pi$ and $\pi \log 3$.

Comment: More hint: the function $f(x) = \log x/ x$ is increasing on the interval $[3,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon: Small typo, the function is decreasing.

Comment: @gammatester Oh, I had been confused.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419563/how-to-prove-that-3-pi-pi3 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966964/which-number-its-greater-pi3-or-3-pi.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consider the function $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{x}$.

Find the derivative of $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{x}$. You will get that the maxima is attained at $x=e$ and that the function is increasing for $x < e$ and decreasing for $x > e$.

Hence you have $x_2^\frac{1}{x_2}\le x_1^\frac{1}{x_1}$ $\forall$ $x_2> x_1 >e$ and $ \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now $\pi > 3 > e$

So we have $$\pi^\frac{1}{\pi} < 3^\frac{1}{3}$$ and hence your result $$\pi^3 < 3^\pi$$

Comment: @lhf I have corrected my answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

By *relation* here, it is meant

> Which relation holds: $\pi^3 < 3^\pi$,  $\pi^3 = 3^\pi$, or  $\pi^3 > 3^\pi$ ?

Rewrite this comparison to compare $\pi^{1/\pi}$ and $3^{1/3}$:

> Which relation holds: $\pi^{1/\pi} < 3^{1/3}$,  $\pi^{1/\pi} = 3^{1/3}$, or  $\pi^{1/\pi} > 3^{1/3}$ ?

Then this is a classical problem, whose solution clearly now lies in considering the function $x^{1/x}$ and where it is monotone. You'll see that the only thing special about $\pi$ and $3$ is that $\pi > 3$.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419563/how-to-prove-that-3-pi-pi3 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966964/which-number-its-greater-pi3-or-3-pi.